# Magento 2: How do I add attributes to a custom EAV model collection?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, data-provider

Using Magento 2.1.3: I want to display custom EAV attributes in a admin grid, but can't figure out how to properly add them to the data provider collection. I would assume this would work, but it's throwing an undefined method error on `addAttributeToSelect`:

```
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Ui\Component\Listing\DataProviders\Namespace\Obj;

class Grid extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{    
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    \Vendor\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Obj\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $this->collection->load();
}
}
```

My `\Vendor\Namespace\Model\ResourceModel\Obj\Collection` class extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`

I have also now tried loading the product model, then getting the collection, and still no luck, however loading a obj directly contains the attributes:

```
....
_construct(
    ....
    \Vendor\Namespace\Model\ObjFactory $objFactory,
     ....
) {
   $obj = $objFactory->create()->load([id]);
   var_dump($obj->getData()); // has attributes
   $objCollection = $obj->getCollection();
   foreach ($objCollection as $cObj) {
        var_dump($cObj->getData()); // no attributes
   }
}
```

Comment: It's custom EAV grid? Or which grid?

Comment: Hi @SohelRana - it's a custom grid, defined in a ui_component xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource model you're extending does not have an addAttributeToSelect method and is not intended to be used for EAV entities.

Your collection should extend \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection instead.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - that did it - I'm seeing a different issue now with the grid, but changing the parent collection class allowed me to run addAttributeToSelect('*') to the collection and I am seeing the attribute values in the loaded objects. Incidentally, changing the class also changed the main table name from 'main_table' to 'e'

Comment: When loading EAV entities Magento tends to give the main table an alias of e (entity) instead of main_table